# Creating a web server for communication with Android apps

Tags: android, json, web, server, xampp

I want to create a web server at home and upgrade it to communicate with my Android app. Eventually I would like to store SQL data on it and collect data from it in my Android app. I have no idea where to start, and I am worried that I might start with one tutorial which will eventually not be able to give me the end result I want.(I am looking for tutorials at the moment since I have no knowledge on server side coding or anything similar)

So I was wondering if XAMPP is the thing I am looking for? I found many tutorials on that but I can't find anywhere if it is possible to eventually store my SQL data and communicate with android app. Also I read that XAMPP is for testing purposes and I would like to start learning something I might actually use as a web server later on for commercial apps.

If not, what else can I use? Many websites suggest JSON server communication but I am still not sure if that is the thing I am looking for.

Comment: Do you know how to communicate from Android side?

Comment: I have experience working with Parse, Firebase and other similar web servers, but have no idea how to do that without their APIs (and without their web server). That's the thing I am interested in learning.

Comment: you can use localhost for storing data in mysql

Comment: @SarvagnaMehta is that the XAMPP solution? And does that mean I can eventually use localhost for commercial apps which communicate with server?(or something similar) I am worried that I might end up learning something i won't be able to use in a situation other than home testing

Comment: That is the solution for using xampp for testing your app, If you wish to publish your app you should need a webhosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install xamp on your pc
2. Create the php file to communicate with the android data
3. Use http://10.0.2.2:80/ as a server ip in your android project

Consider Following link for more information
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: `10.0.2.2' ???? That is only if the app runs in an emulator on the same computer as the server. Nowhere i can find that OP uses an emulator.

Comment: Thanks, if I understood you correctly, I will use xampp to practice in local environment and that setup could later be ported to a webhosting service, right?